# Strange CSS Behaviour, white space on top of body

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have such a DOM in my website:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='topbar'/>
        <div id='centerframe'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

with the css rules:

```
html
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body
{

    background:url('/images/brickwall.jpg'); background-size: 10%;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:0;
}

div#centerframe
{

    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    box-shadow:0em 0.5em 2em 0.3em;
    padding:90px;
    margin-left:        180px;
    margin-right:       160px;  
    margin-top:         200px; /* this also causes body to slide down 200px , when body{padding-top:0} . why ? */

}

#topbar
{
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    top:0;
    margin-top:0%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

and this css causes such a problem: body has a margin on top, even though i told it to `margin:0;` here's the screen cap:
[image: problem]

but when I change the css, and make `body{padding-top: 1px;}` (instead of 0), it works as it should. see the screen cap:
[image: normal]

It also works when I add this rule: `#centerframe{float:left;}` but it causes other problems, like expanding to more than 100% width.

Anyway, so I solved the problem with a 1px padding. But why the problem was there at the first place?

How can a child of `<body/>` change its top margin?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is caused by [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) due to how browsers handle succeeding elements including the image you show. This is proved by your adding the padding but I have not tested this.

Be aware that, in your example, `<div />` is invalid. Divs are not self closing.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to recreate this behaviour in jsFiddle, so I can't say anything specific about it. Do you know if it is a browser issue?

Your body sure does not have a margin, because the topbar is always at the very top, so that's where your body starts. Maybe it is just background that is displaced (for some awkward reason). Did you play around with the background-position property?